# How to get the raw content of a response in requests with Python?

Tags: python, http, web, request, python-requests

Trying to get the raw data of the HTTP response content in `requests` in Python. I am interested in forwarding the response through another channel, which means that ideally the content should be as pristine as possible.

What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are using a `requests.get` call to obtain your HTTP response, you can use the `raw` attribute of the response.  Here is the code from the [`requests` docs](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content).  The `stream=True` parameter in the `requests.get` call is required for this to work.

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json', stream=True)
>>> r.raw
<requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x101194810>
>>> r.raw.read(10)
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03'
```

Comment: OK, that seems like it's promising... How would I get the whole data from that?

Comment: looks like it's `r.raw.data`

Comment: This doesnt seem to work correctly, I tried `res.raw.data` and `res.raw.read(100)` but they both return empty.

Comment: @DoronCohen Did you include `stream=True` ?

Comment: you could use use `r.raw.decode_content = True` to handle `Content-Encoding` http header.

Comment: @farthVader Thanks, I missed that one.

Comment: You specifically said if you have used "get"; Does that mean we cannot use this for response object generated as a result of "post"?

Comment: @farthVader that hint with `stream=True` was a lifesaver! It should be a separate answer, because I had the exact same problem, and only that small change did it.

Comment: @Devolus Actually the hyperlinked docs emphasize this(make sure `stream=True` before access `r.raw`). I'd like to edit this answer, but the edit queue is full.

Comment: I've edited the answer to emphasize the requirement of `stream=True`.

Comment: This response is incomplete without mentioning `r.content` as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46772625/1048186)

Answer (score 39):

After `requests.get()`, you can use `r.content` to extract the raw Byte-type content.

```
r = requests.get('https://yourweb.com', stream=True)
r.content
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to @blair answer, as stated in the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content):

> In general, however, you should use a pattern like this to save what is being streamed to a file:

```
r = requests.get('https://yourweb.com', stream=True)

with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
   for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
      fd.write(chunk)
```

> Using Response.iter_content will handle a lot of what you would otherwise have to handle when using Response.raw directly. When streaming a download, the above is the preferred and recommended way to retrieve the content. Note that chunk_size can be freely adjusted to a number that may better fit your use cases.

That pattern not only has the advantages described above, but is also a good to fetch data in environments with limited memory.

Comment: Doesn't seem a complete answer. What is `r`?

Comment: I edited to add clarity, but had you looked at the two other answers, I was simply following their pattern of setting `r` to be the request object.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me.  Thanks.  I also thought that 'r' is intuitive (esp. given the other responses).

Answer (score 2):

The following is an easy way to recreate the whole HTTP response, including the HTTP header's initial Status Line:

```
r = requests.get('https://yourweb.com/', stream=True)
print(f"HTTP/{r.raw.version/10} {r.raw.status} {r.raw.reason}")
for k,v in r.raw.headers.items(): print(f"{k}: {v}")
print(r.text)
```

This may not be 100% pristine, but it should be very close.  And you could use print()'s `file=` parameter to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Adding `header_reply = {}` above the first line and changing `print(f"{k}: {v}")` to `header_reply[k]=v` makes a quick dictionary. Handy for wrangling API's and such that don't return any content.