# Python hdfs : Cannot read file

Tags: python, json, hadoop, hdfs, python-requests

I am trying to read a file from hdfds using python as

```
from hdfs.client import Client
import json,requests
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cl = Client("http://hostName:port")
    print cl.list("/myDir/")
    with cl.read("/myDir/myFile.json") as f:
        print f
        print json.load(f)
```

but i get

```
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

on `json.load(f)`

i also tried

```
with cl.read("/myDir/myFile.json", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
```

but now i get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

then i tried

```
with cl.read("/myDir/myFile.json",encoding ="utf-8", errors='ignore') as f:
```

but i get

```
TypeError: read() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'
```

is there any way i can read the file in as a simple string? The file looks like

```
{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"...}
```

i am using python 2.7

**Update**

Thanks @Yaron for the helpful suggestion. After some fiddling, i came up with this

```
r=requests.get('http://hostName:port/webhdfs/v1/myDir/myFile.json?op=OPEN', stream=True)
r.raw.decode_content = True
print r
print str(r.raw.read())
```

however, for some reason, it does not read the entire file. It kind of just stops in the middle, and i dont know why. Any idea?

Plus, i still cant convert it to JSON. I tried

```
r=requests.get('http://hostName:port/webhdfs/v1/myDir/myFile.json?op=OPEN', stream=True)
r.raw.decode_content = True
print r
x=r.raw.read()
# print x["key1"] fails citing that string indices must be integers
print x
x=json.loads(str(x))
```

and i get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

back to square 1!

**Finally got it**

all i had to do was

```
r=requests.get('http://hostName:port/webhdfs/v1/myDir/myFile.json?op=OPEN', stream=True)
r.raw.decode_content = True
print r
x=r.raw.read().decode("utf-8",errors="ignore")
print json.loads(x)["key1"]
```

and this gives me

```
<Response [200]>
value2
```

:)

Comment: Instead of running "json.load(f)" - Can you please try executing "json.loads(f)?

Comment: `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: `print f` gives `<requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x0000000006768K0G1>` so its clearly some kind of object. is there a way to read this using `requests.get()`

Comment: 1) see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdfs/ - I'd follow their example step-by-step (which seems very similar to what you did) - and make sure that the problem is not in the python code. 2) the next step is to confirm that /myDir/myFile.json actually exists in the HDFS, and holds a valid json file

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i am doing. and the file is there. i can even download it and see the content using the webhdfs ui

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16924225/5088142 - explain that you can read requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object using object..raw.read(10) - e.g. f.raw.read(10)

Comment: Please add your solution below as an answer instead of adding it to the question

Comment: i agree, @Yaron, please add your suggestion as an answer

Comment: @abtpst & cricket - done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) see [pypi.python.org/pypi/hdfs](https://pypi.org/project/hdfs/) - I'd follow their example step-by-step (which seems very similar to what you did) - and make sure that the problem is not in the python code. 2) the next step is to confirm that `/myDir/myFile.json` actually exists in the HDFS, and holds a valid json file.

[stackoverflow.com/a/16924225/5088142](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923898/how-to-get-the-raw-content-of-a-response-in-requests-with-python/16924225#16924225) - explain that you can read `requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse` object using `object.raw.read(10)` - e.g. `f.raw.read(10)`

Comment: this works! however, i still cant convert it to json using json.load() or json.loads(). i am thinking it has to do with the json library. any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share the raw data which you wish to read with json.load?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried one of:

- [snakebite](https://github.com/spotify/snakebite) or
- [hdfs3](https://github.com/dask/hdfs3)

These should allow very easy way to read files as simple content in *python* specifically. Also those are pure python hdfs clients, instead of web/http hdfs wrappers.

In snakebite for example it would be:

```
from snakebite.client import AutoConfigClient
c = AutoConfigClient()
next(c.text([“/user/r/foobar.txt"]))
`awesome foobar content`
```

EDIT: when it comes to json example:

```
> jq . test.json
{
   "bar": "test",
   "foo": 1
}
> hdfs dfs -put test.json
> snakebite cat test.json | jq .
{
   "bar": "test",
   "foo": 1
}
> python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from snakebite.client import AutoConfigClient
>>> c = AutoConfigClient()
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> next(c.text(["test.json"]))
'{"foo": 1, "bar": "test"}\n'
>>> json.loads(next(c.text(["test.json"])))
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 'test'}
```

Comment: snakebite is awesome! thanks. i think i can read the file using cl.cat as well but still cant convert it to json using json.load() or json.loads(). i am thinking it has to do with the json library. any suggestions?

Comment: thanks man! i figured it out. please see the edit. i had to accept @Yaron's answer as he had posted earlier. i just could not figure out the decode part.

Comment: @AbtPst np - btw added example with json to the answer too

Answer (score 0):

```
 with cl.read('/myDir/myFile.json', encoding='utf-8') as reader:
       from json import load
        model = load(reader)
```

Comment: this is what i tried in the first place. i get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`

Comment: Do you get the listing from `print cl.list("/myDir/")`. The post above doesn't have it.

Comment: Alright. Its to do with the json file you have. What string did you see from `print f`. Does it look like printable characters?