# Convert urllib3.response.HTTPResponse to plain text response

Tags: python, for-loop, url, python-requests

I'm running the below code to try to get a plain text response that should be a url. After running it I get

```html
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x102659210>
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x1026598d0>
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x1026595d0>
```

Is there any way to convert these responses into the actual plain text url? Also when checking the data in Postman, I'd prefer to return the Raw body if that's possible.

```html
for data in my_folder["data"]:
    contact = data["contact"] 
    get_endpoint = base_url + str(contact)
    endpoint = requests.get(get_endpoint,headers=headers)
    print(endpoint.raw)
```

Comment: Partially related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16923898/1804173), the difference being: The other question only wants the "content" whereas this question is interested in the full raw response, i.e., including headers/cookies/... which would indeed be helpful for debugging the full HTTP communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `response.data`... see the docs [here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.response.html#urllib3.response.HTTPResponse.data)

Comment: This is an answer on an older question, but doesn't provide much information. In this case, the docs only indicate that the property data exists, and that it's bytes, and your answer adds little to anyone's understanding. Can you provide an example of how to get the plain text url from response.data?