# Error when passing URLs into a requests.get()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I've been working on a program that takes URLs from a .csv and counts the word amount on the webpage. The URLs come from the rows under the "Article" column in a pandas dataframe. The URLs are inputted into a requests.get(url) set to a variable. In my investigation of the error, the problem arises when the URL is inputted into the requrests.get().

```
def file_input(file):
   #takes a .csv file from the user
   df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='[;,]', engine='python')
   for i in range(len(df)):
     df.at[i, "Word Count"] = word_counter(df.at[i, "Article"])
```

```
def word_counter(url):
  #keeps tracks of the page's word count
  count = 0
  #the requests.get(url) takes the string of url and gets the access of the webpage
  page = requests.get(url)
```

here are the error mesages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 406, in _decode
    data = self._decoder.decompress(data)
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 93, in decompress
    ret += self._obj.decompress(data)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 816, in generate
    yield from self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True)
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 627, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 599, in read
    data = self._decode(data, decode_content, flush_decoder)
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 409, in _decode
    raise DecodeError(
urllib3.exceptions.DecodeError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 44, in main
    file_input(file)
  File "main.py", line 35, in file_input
    df.at[i, "Word Count"] = word_counter(df.at[i, "Article"])
  File "main.py", line 13, in word_counter
    page = requests.get(anything)
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 745, in send
    r.content
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 899, in content
    self._content = b"".join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b""
  File "/home/runner/Article-Word-counter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 820, in generate
    raise ContentDecodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check'))
```

Comment: What is the error? (with full stack trace, please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError:
> ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.',
> error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check'))

It seems the server's response states that it is gzip-encoded, but `requests` failed to decode it when it treated it as gzipped. This could be a server misconfiguration, or something more subtle. Try to request a non-compressed response by specifying the [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header (though it is possible the server will not respect your request):

```
headers = { 'Accept-Encoding': 'identity' }
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

You can also check whether you can access the URL using other tools, like `curl`, or your web browser. Additionally, you can explicitly check the [raw response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923898/how-to-get-the-raw-content-of-a-response-in-requests-with-python) to see what the server is actually sending you. But it seems contacting the webmaster of the URL in question might be the real solution.